# Change relationships with Entity Framework Core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I am new to Entity Framework Core and Code First. In my design approach I have made mistake between two entities.

I have created a table *subCourses* which is currently set to have a one to many relationships with *Instructors*. This would mean that a sub course can have many instructors, herein lies my mistake, I want it the other way around so that a instructor can have many sub courses.

I have not yet created any controllers or generated any views or filled in any data to these tables.

This is the abbreviated Models code for the subCourse:

```
public class SubCourse
{

    //Constructor
    public SubCourse()
    {
        Instructors = new List<Instructor>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int SubCourseID { get; set; }


    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(10)")]
    [DisplayName(" Local Course Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must fill in Local Sub Course name.")]
    public string LocalCourseCode { get; set; }

    public List<Instructor> Instructors { get; set; }
}
```

This is the abbreviated Models code for the Instructors:

```
public class Instructor
{
    [Key]
    public int InstructorID { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(50)")]
    [DisplayName("First Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must fill in the first name.")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(50)")]
    [DisplayName("Last Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must fill in the last name.")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public SubCourse SubCourse { get; set; }
    public int SubCourseID { get; set; }

}
```

What do I need to change in my structure to make the switch in my relationships, and could I then afterwards in package manager console just do a change of:

> Add-Migration ChangeRelationInstructorSubCourse
>
> Update-Database

Comment: I am assuming One(Instructor) To Many (sub-courses) Relationship and not Many to Many, if so, Remove SubCourseID from Instructor, and make SubCourse Property to be of type  ICollection<SubCourse> then add an Instructor property and InstructorID property to SubCourse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want create a one-to-many relationship between Instructor and SubCourse ,you could just change the model design like below:

```
 public class SubCourse
{

    [Key]
    public int SubCourseID { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(10)")]
    [DisplayName(" Local Course Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must fill in Local Sub Course name.")]
    public string LocalCourseCode { get; set; }

    public int InstructorID { get; set; }
    public Instructor Instructor { get; set; }
}

public class Instructor
{
    public Instructor()
    {
        SubCourses = new List<SubCourse>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int InstructorID { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(50)")]
    [DisplayName("First Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must fill in the first name.")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(50)")]
    [DisplayName("Last Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must fill in the last name.")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public List<SubCourse> SubCourses { get; set; }
}
```

Then generate a new migration file that contains the new relationship in Package Manager Console

```
Add-Migration ChangeRelationInstructorSubCourse
```

Update the new relationship into database

```
Update-Database
```

For the relationships in EF Core , you could take aside time to learning [the official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key)